# Как сохранить проект на WP после завершения в минимальных размерах?

Tags: wordpress

Проектов на WP, тестовых и коммерческих, несколько десятков на компьютере. Память на компьютере не резиновая. С одной стороны хочу сохранить проекты, с другой - освободить место.

Есть ли способ хранить БД и тему (и всё остальное важное, если оно есть), без движка (и всего остального не важного, если оно есть)?

Comment: Память... ОМГ...  А архив движка в занимает каких-то 10мб.

Comment: Используйте github, и храните там всё важное, включая дамп базы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно все сайты оформить в виде мультисайта. Тогда все сайты будут использовать одно ядро wordpress и один набор плагинов

https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/wordpress/ustanovka-multisite-mu

Comment: Не факт, что один набор плагинов возможен в его случае. И таблиц в БД будет ровно такое кол-во, как сайтов x кол-во таблиц в сайте. За небольшим вычетом.

Comment: @KAGGDesign набор плагинов в плане, что место сократится из-за отсутствия дублей плагинов.

Comment: Я это понимаю прекрасно, только подозреваю, что проекты у него вообще все разные, с разным набором плагинов.